# How to Get Apache Commons Zip-- Zip64 to Work

Tags: java, zip, apache-commons

**Question:**
I have been struggling to get the Apache Commons Zip 64 functionality to work and specifically the ZipArchiveOutputStream.setUseZip64() method. When I attempt to use this method, I get a "The method setUseZip64(Zip64Mode) is undefined for the type ZipArchiveOutputStream" error. Why might this error be occurring?

**What I Tried**
I have spent quite some time on this. I add (and verify) the external JAR file to the project. From what I see in Eclipse, when I attempt to instantiate a ZipArchiveOutputStream, oddly, the signature of the object becomes:

> org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream.ZipArchiveOutputStream

Note the duplicate signature as

> ZipArchiveOutputStream.ZipArchiveOutputStream
>   .

Alternatively, I manually added the source code to the actual project build. When I manually add the source code to the project, ODDLY, the method works--that is, I can call the

> zipout.setUseZip64(Zip64Mode.Always)

without issue (and the signature seems to not duplicate as above).

Ideally, I simply want to reference the external Apache JAR file rather than internally adding the source. Thus, why might this error be occurring?

Note: I also built my own compiled version of the Apache Source as a separate JAR and this also exhibits the error described. Thus, only a manual add of the code to the actual Eclipse Project seems to help.

Note: I made sure that there is not a conflict between the manually added version and the external JAR reference.

**Code Example**

```
import org.apache.commons.compress.*;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.*;
...
ZipArchiveOutputStream zipout = 
    new ZipArchiveOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filenameandpath));
zipout.setUseZip64(Zip64Mode.Always) ; // ERROR HERE The method setUseZip64(Zip64Mode) 
                                       // is undefined for the type 
                                       // ZipArchiveOutputStream
```

**Configuration**
Eclipse 3.7 (and 4.2)
Java 1.6
Apache Commons Compress (version 1.3 and newer 1.4)

Answer (score 0):

After a few months of addressing this problem, the solution came by accident.

The problem arises if one imports BOTH Apache Commons Zip AND Mahout Distribution 0.5.

Specifically, there is a subtle import conflict in

```
mahout-examples-0.5.jar 
mahout-examples-0.5-job.jar
```

which also apparently uses an older version of Apache Commons. The import order caused a subtle conflict rendering more recent Apache Commons functionality ineffective--except when I manually imported the Commons Compress code (only to test) into the project--effectively subverting the real conflict with Mahout.